# Text Distortion Effect (like it is written on a page)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, effects, transform, distort

I want to display a text like it is written on some surface like notebook page or wall via Photoshop CS6. I added two example.

This image seems like image distortion:

[image]

And this image looks like text distortion:

[image]

I tried this with distort and skew transformation but I'm unable to get this much clear & real effect.

Comment: If any of the answers below answers your question, please tick the "accepted"-tick-mark next to it, to mark it as the useful answers. StackExchange relies on this, and it is good for us all. If you did not get a good answer, perhaps edit your question to be more specific of what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to apply a texture or some text and curve it in a custom way, there is a way to do this without using any filter and it gives you also more control.

You could try the "free transform" command on your image in Adobe Photoshop (Command + T), and then right-click on your image and use the "warp" command.

It may not be obvious but some bezier handles will appear on each corner of your image (as the ones in Illustrator) and you can play around with each of them to warp your image the way you want. You can still use the "free transform" on each each corner to add some perspective if you need to. The final result will depend on your own skills!

[image: Warp and Free transform commands in Adobe Photoshop]

Answer (score 2):

You can make a smart object, double click it to open it and put your text on that, save and then go back to your main document and distort the smart object.

You can also use free transform like above but I have found better to use my method because after you distort you can still edit your text, free transform required a raterized layer.

Answer (score 2):

What you have shown uses only three things, Smart Objects (you may not need it depending on how complex the design is) , Perspective and Distort , both found in the Transform menu (Ctrl + T).

You mentioned your design isn't as clear, that depends on the resolution of the distorted layer and the level of distortion.

This isn't quite something you nail the first time, you have to play a little with it. Good luck!

Also, for the realistic effect you have to take into account the highlights and shades too, along with surface textures and so on.