# How to create the 3D mock-up look

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mockup, isometric

I saw this on Dribbble and I thought I'd have a go at reproducing it - https://dribbble.com/shots/2200956-Controlled-Content

But i'm struggling to do so. I've had a play around with shear and rotating but I can't seem to get it to look quite right.

Here's my attempt. I feel like I lose all the readability in the text. The angle matches the top of the paper, but the angle of the text doesn't match the sides. Is there a set way to get this angle/effect or is it just done by eye?

[image]

Comment: Use the Warp or Free Transform, align your logo with the same angle as the page (your logo lacks perspective). See this: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35565/text-distortion-effect-like-it-is-written-on-a-page/54940#54940

Comment: It's all about perspective. There is even a perspective transform tool in photoshop. If you want to go isometric, make sure the 3D settings to your objects are the same.

Comment: @KMSTR you cant make iometric with teh perspective tool

Comment: Why would you even? Perspective -> Perspective tool, isometric -> 3d tool.

Comment: Ah ok @KMSTR, Anyway its not that simple you need to know the projection

Comment: Which you do, when you create both.

Comment: relevant and an attempt at a blanket answer: [How to mockup a logo in a realistic environment?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113783/how-to-mockup-a-logo-in-a-realistic-environment)